# cupy add working differently in different environments on same machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cupy

I started implementing a DL code, and this is my first time with DL, GPUs, and Cupy. I made a toy example that works differently in different python envs on the same machine, and I am looking to understand in detail what and why of this happening.

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

X = 150000
Y = 100
Z = 79

shape_pca_mean = np.random.rand(X, 1)

shape_pca_basis = np.random.rand(X, Y)
shape_pca_basis_gpu = cp.asarray(shape_pca_basis)

shape_params = np.random.rand(Y, 1)
shape_params_gpu = cp.asarray(shape_params)

shape_x = shape_pca_basis_gpu.dot(shape_params_gpu)

exp_pca_basis = np.random.rand(X, Z)
exp_pca_basis_gpu = cp.asarray(exp_pca_basis)

exp_params = np.random.rand(Z, 1)
exp_params_gpu = cp.asarray(exp_params)

exp_x = exp_pca_basis_gpu.dot(exp_params_gpu)

a = shape_pca_mean + cp.asnumpy(exp_x) + cp.asnumpy(shape_x)
```

I have 2 Python environments. A global python3 and a local virtualenv python 3. They both have the same versions of NumPy, cupy, cupy-cuda110, and other python libs installed. The above code works well in both the envs.

However, if I add one more line below, the virtualenv python3 works well, but I get the following error if running on global Python.

```
b = cp.asarray(shape_pca_mean) + exp_x + shape_x
```

Error

```
$ python3 scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch.py", line 18, in <module>
    a = cp.asarray(shape_pca_mean) + exp_x + shape_x
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 968, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.__add__
  File "cupy/core/_kernel.pyx", line 951, in cupy.core._kernel.ufunc.__call__
  File "cupy/core/_kernel.pyx", line 974, in cupy.core._kernel.ufunc._get_ufunc_kernel
  File "cupy/core/_kernel.pyx", line 714, in cupy.core._kernel._get_ufunc_kernel
  File "cupy/core/_kernel.pyx", line 61, in cupy.core._kernel._get_simple_elementwise_kernel
  File "cupy/core/carray.pxi", line 196, in cupy.core.core.compile_with_cache
  File "/home/ppinazuredlvm1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/cuda/compiler.py", line 298, in compile_with_cache
    extra_source, backend)
  File "/home/ppinazuredlvm1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/cuda/compiler.py", line 352, in _compile_with_cache_cuda
    ls.add_ptr_data(ptx, 'cupy.ptx')
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 230, in cupy.cuda.function.LinkState.add_ptr_data
  File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 232, in cupy.cuda.function.LinkState.add_ptr_data
  File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 198, in cupy.cuda.driver.linkAddData
  File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 118, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_PTX: a PTX JIT compilation failed
```

If it helps, more details on my system and drivers, etc are present in [this cupy issue](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/3974#issue-697061728).

It doesn't look like the usual driver incompatibility issue, as if that were the case, the above code wouldn't run on any env.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that you have both cupy and cupy-cudaXXX installed, which would lead to all sorts of weird issues. If so, remove cupy and stick to the wheel version.